# Call ffmpeg in c++ with system() function fails

Tags: ffmpeg

I write a c++ program which needs to convert some(say:10) mp4 videos to flv videos.
I use ffmpeg in my program for each video like this:

```
system("ffmpeg -i video -filter:v yadif -ar 44100 -sameq -y -f flv temp.flv")
```

however,it turns out:**only first video will be converted successfully,the others will fail.**
it means:
when i change the input order of which video to convert and re-execution the program,it behave the same:only the first video(will be different each time as i changed the input video order) will be converted successfully.

**The error message like:**

[h264 @ 0xaee0740] concealing 45 DC, 45 AC, 45 MV errors
[h264 @ 0xaee0ce0] AVC: nal size 305665
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0xaee0ce0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0xaee1280] AVC: nal size 572993
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0xaee1280] no frame!
[aac @ 0xad9ccc0] channel element 0.13 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1
[aac @ 0xad9ccc0] channel element 0.13 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1
[aac @ 0xad9ccc0] channel element 0.13 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1
......
The most strange thing is :**when i run ffmpeg command in bash shell,all video will be converted successfully** .

After google it,I have try these(certainly failed):

1. remove -sameq option,the result is same;
2. write ffmpeg commod in a shell script ConvertToFlv.sh like:

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$dir/$1" -filter:v yadif -ar 44100 -sameq -y -f flv "$dir/temp.fiv"
   ```

   then call this script in program like

   ```
   system("ConvertToFlv.sh"+video)
   ```

   or

   ```
   system("sh ConvertToFlv.sh"+video)
   ```

   The result is same.

The ffmpeg configure is:

```
  ffmpeg version 0.9.1.git Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 17 2012 16:17:30 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfaac --disable-ffserver --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      51. 41.100 / 51. 41.100
  libavcodec     54.  4.100 / 54.  4.100
  libavformat    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 62.101 /  2. 62.101
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  7.100 /  0.  7.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
```

and my machine envirment is:

```
Linux master 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 14:58:14 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm irritable now,I hope someone can give me some advice,really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried the latest FFmpeg?

Comment: Also, if you're just changing container formats (and not codecs or other things), you can specify `-acodec copy -vcodec copy` to avoid re-encoding.

Comment: @Cornstalks Actually,my program work well with older versions.After I install ffmpeg 0.9.1 in another machine where i run the program,It doesn't work

Comment: @Cornstalks I just install ffmpeg 0.11.2,it's all the same!Confused.

Comment: I honestly can't see why those errors wouldn't exist when using it from the command line...

Comment: How are your 10 videos named? and what is the output filenames for each of them? Are you overwriting them by anychance?

Comment: The 10 orignal videos are named end with .mp4,the output videos are named end with .flv.